# How to manage Downloadable Product storage location in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database, downloadable, system.xml

I have a Magento store hosting mp3/mp4 as Downloadable Products. The storage capacity for the location of these products `media\downloadable\files\links\` is limited and because of the amount of space that these files take, the drive is outgrowing substantially. My question, can the location of this files be linked to an attached storage, disk drive, or network drive other than the default location set by the Magento store? And if yes, what configuration/modules needs to be modified or is there an extension that can handle it? Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: you can use a symlink from that path to your mounted storage...

Comment: Thanks Chis, is that an extension package or is a built-in feature?

Comment: ask your sysadmin. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this was to use `Links` for downloadable products, instead of `Files`. `Files` would take a lot of drive storage and would cause performance issues on the server that host the store. Basically, I created another server/container that could host the media files and link them to the Magento store. This solution is similar to a `CDN (Content Delivery Network)`. It's more efficient and links are encrypted by default from the Magento store, meaning that the `URL'S` are secured and not pull in a `RAW Format`. I hope this could help someone, Thanks!